# Странные однокоренные слова

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Сейчас наткнулся в Интернете на странное утверждение, что в русском языке слова "бык" и "пчела" однокоренные. Как такое может быть? В этих словах ведь даже одинаковых букв нет. Кроме того, что может объединять два этих живых существа?
Или, может быть, это утверждение неверно - сейчас в Интернете чего только не пишут.
Хотелось бы узнать мнение специалиста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Жук - жужжит, шмель - шумит, бык и пчела - бучат (гудят). Все эти слова звукоподражательные.

Прежнее название пчелы - БЪКЬЛА, потом произошло чередование К/Ч,  в сильной позиции под ударением  вместо ерь(Ь) произносится Е, а  ер (Ъ) в слабой позиции перестал произноситься.

Comment: А как в данном случае читаются твердые знаки? В смысле, какая огласовка у этого слова?

Comment: Например, в XII веке  в «Русской Правде» Владимира Мономаха упоминаются "бъчелы", а произносилось слово как   "бочела или бучела".